# I'm trying to upload a file to sanity client with client.assets.upload

Tags: javascript, sanity

I catch this error when I've try to upload to sanity client. Is it the lengthComputable or something else that is the problem and if so how do I fix it?

[Caught Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1tO8.png)

```
client.assets
        .upload('file', selectedFile, { contentType: selectedFile.type, filename: selectedFile.name })
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("Upload failed: ", error)
        })
```

selected File is a vid btw. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I've tried to use await but the documentation does not say I have to.